# Simple php search form with break

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, break

I have a simple system for search and compare results.

In this case I'll have 2 results ok and one bad.

For use this I use the following code:

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof("search.txt");$i++)
{

    if ($_REQUEST['search']=="ok" && $_REQUEST['car']=="")
    {
        print "ok";
        break;
        /// show results;
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['search']=="ok" && $_REQUEST['car']=="" && $_REQUEST['city']=="")
    {
        print "ok";
        break;
        /// show results;
    }
}
```

The problem it's if the result must show 2 results, the line "break" stops the loop, but if I don't put break, it shows me results of other conditional "if", I put simple example, because into this loop I have many conditionals "if", by this I need to show all results in each case and break for each conditional, but break cur me the loop into the loop and no let continue

My question is if I can use break for do or need use other function let me do this, because I need do by this way

Thanks Regards

Answer (score 2):

`break` is intended for case statements and loops. Since you're not using a case, the `break` will break the foreach. You probably want `continue` to move on to the next iteration.

e.g.

```
for(...) {
   if (something) {
      ...
      continue; // "break" this loop iteration and move on to the next one.
   }
   if (something else) {
       ...
       break; // kills the foreach and moves down to the "stuff after loop" below.
   } 
   switch (this_and_that) {
      case 'a': ...; break; // breaks out of the switch and moves to "stuff after switch"
      case 'b': ...; break; // ditto
   }
   ... stuff after switch ...
}

... stuff after loop ...
```

Comment: not sure what you're trying to get at with your code. you've got your breaks before "show results", so the show results code would never get executed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it this way:

```
if ($_REQUEST['search']=="ok" && $_REQUEST['car']=="")
{
print "ok";
   if ($_REQUEST['city']=="")
   {
   break;
   }
break;
}
```

because once first if-statement is true, the second will only need 'city' to be true.